# Undefined Index : HotelImages - Expedia

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have the following snippet, taken from http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotel-info/examples/rest-default-content

```
[ "HotelImages": {
            "@size": "16",
            "HotelImage": [
                {
                    "hotelImageId": 4694179,
                    "name": "",
                    "category": 1,
                    "type": 0,
                    "caption": "Exterior",
                    "url": "/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_b.jpg",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_t.jpg",
                    "supplierId": 13,
                    "width": 350,
                    "height": 350,
                    "byteSize": 0
                },
                {
                    "hotelImageId": 4694182,
                    "name": "",
                    "category": 2,
                    "type": 0,
                    "caption": "Lobby",
                    "url": "/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_b.jpg",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_t.jpg",
                    "supplierId": 13,
                    "width": 350,
                    "height": 350,
                    "byteSize": 0
                }, ]
```

How can get the data of `url`? It's actually a URL which we should append with http://images.travelnow.com/

Example : `echo $data['HotelImages']['HotelImage']['url'];`

But it gives me the following error

> undefined index : HotelImages

How can I resolve this?

Comment: What are you showing us? It looks like a mix of PHP array syntax and JSON, but valid for neither.

Comment: $data is in JSON FORMAT, let's say our data is stored in mongo db as JSON format. now I want to get the data of the 'url' field to my blades. how can I do this.

Comment: Well, what you've provided isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Let me edit it. That's not the point anyway!

Comment: It is part of the point. If you give us rubbish, then we have to make assumptions / guesses rather than being able to help give an answer.

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry.

Comment: The update still isn't valid JSON...

Comment: I got it from here main vendor API website. http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotel-info/examples/rest-default-content

Comment: I get all the other data such as name, address, city but I cannot fetch url, thumbNailUrl data. I've tried with array_key_exists(key, $var); yet no luck.

Comment: If you did a basic `json_decode($string);` on that JSON example, you'd access url via something like `$data->HotelImages->HotelImage[0]->url`.

Comment: We have our data json_decode($data, true); on our model query and can access all the data except 'url' and 'thumbNailUrl' on our blade file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your JSON sytax and try

```
 $data ='{"HotelImages": {
            "@size": "16",
            "HotelImage": [
                {
                    "hotelImageId": 4694179,
                    "name": "",
                    "category": 1,
                    "type": 0,
                    "caption": "Exterior",
                    "url": "hxxp://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_b.jpg",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "hxxp://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_t.jpg",
                    "supplierId": 13,
                    "width": 350,
                    "height": 350,
                    "byteSize": 0
                },
                {
                    "hotelImageId": 4694182,
                    "name": "",
                    "category": 2,
                    "type": 0,
                    "caption": "Lobby",
                    "url": "hxxp://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_b.jpg",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "hxxp://media.expedia.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_t.jpg",
                    "supplierId": 13,
                    "width": 350,
                    "height": 350,
                    "byteSize": 0
                }]}}';

    $k =  json_decode($data); 
    print_r($k->HotelImages->HotelImage[0]->url); 
    exit();
```